# How can I get the current Fragment from ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm an Android application that have one activity that have a ViewPager with 4 Fragments.

Now I'm building a OnPageChangeListener and in the method onPageSelected I want to get the current fragment that the user can see. So I have used this code:

```
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                Fragment currFragment = null;
                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                List<Fragment> fragments = fm.getFragments();
 //TO DO
}
```

but the list of Fragment contains only 3 Fragment instead of 4. Why ?

How can I get the current Fragment ?

Comment: It is probably because at a same there is only three instances of the fragment, generated by the ViewPagerAdapter. You need to implement more, maybe use some interfaces between your activity and fragments.

Comment: also try to get the second fragment from your list, it is probably the current fragment:
`fragments.get(1)`